# Install4j: how to specify a password value in Java Invocation of Launcher

Tags: passwords, installation, install4j

In `Install4j`, I have a form to let the user configure a login/password (with the variable names: `login` and `password`)

Then I want to create a launcher using the login/password values in Java Invocation Launcher.

See the screenshot below.

1. How can I debug to see the value of these arguments after the installation ?
2. The `${installer:password}` is really the entered value by the user ?

[image]

Comment: ${installer:password} value is "null" string

Answer (score 1):

You probably use a "Password field" form component. The bound variable for a password field component is not written to the response file. That's why it's not available for the launchers.

Add a "Set a variable" action for another variable, i.e. "clearPassword", set the script to

```
context.getVariable("password")
```

and select the "Register for response file" property of that action. Then you can use `${installer:clearPassword}` in the launcher arguments.

Also you have a typo, it should be `${installer:login}` and not `{installer:login}`.

Comment: Thanks. Notice that the "Set a variable" action must be added before the "Installation" phase. It works as expected. Another question: so the clearPassword will be written in the response file. How can I clear this varialbe, or the whole response file at the end of installation ?