# Install4j: Unix launcher script fragment use installer variable

Tags: java, install4j

In the installer I've a directory selection screen to let the user select and specific directory where program is installed.

Then I want to use this variable in script fragment for unix launchers:

[image]

However then in the launcher generated the variable is not correctly changed and it's used the variable description and not it's value, if I edit the launcher with `vi` I see:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${installer:firefoxDirectory}`

And this is not working.

However for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24776367/1218618) it seems that if this same approach is used in the launcher for the arguments of the "Java invocation" then it works.

What I'm doing wrong? It's possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installer variables are not available the generated shell script.

> However for this question it seems that if this same approach is used in the launcher for the arguments of the "Java invocation" then it works.

In that case the installer variable is replaced in the Java launcher.

In your case, you can run a "Replace installer variables in text files" action on the launcher script after the installation.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!